# Staticly linked library default entry points

Tags: linux, linker, openssl, static-libraries, static-linking

When linking a static lib, can there be a default entry point for that specific library?

I don't think there is, but would like clarification. We need to add an entry point, during linking, for a static library to initiate some initialisation/verification calls.

For example, we have a static library, libstuff.a, and want to be able to call an initStuff() routine within that library, but during load time (or as close to as possible), not runtime as such (I know it's technically runtime, but out of control of any post _start()/main() routine).

*To clarify, this was an attempt to fulfill the needs of the NIST FIPS 140.2 spec, specifically section 9.10 of the [Implementation Guide](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/fips140-2/FIPS1402IG.pdf). This includes data and text segment signature verification (see section 9.10's note 3).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in a way to satisfy the NIST FIPS 140-2 spec.

The only solution to achieve what I was after is to use a shared lib within which an initialisation function is called with a constructor attribute (or a modified .init ELF hook, but constructors are clearer). This ensures the initialisation is called before the app starts.

As archive libs are just a bunch of object files, there's no way to isolate them as a group with their own initialisation routine, only application wide initialisation routines which call into those symbols contained in the archive lib.

Comment: You can have an initialization routine for a bunch of .o files. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter. You can do a similar trick in C as well.

Comment: Added an example for you.

Comment: Maybe I needed a little more clarity in the question as noted by my comment relating to the FIPS NIST certification of a static library. Specifically the library linked must be self contained in a way that the initialisation routine is purely within a boundary containing just those symbols within that library, and that all those symbols, and no others, can be fingerprinted as a whole. This all must happen from within the realm of that linked library alone. This is why this is the correct answer as it can't be done in Linux. No need for the downvote.

Comment: What exactly _the initialisation routine is purely within a boundary containing just those symbols within that library_ means?

Answer (score 2):

A most common way is to expose initialization functions that the user of your library must first invoke before using your library.

In C++ you can have global objects with constructors and destructors. When these objects are in a static library though, they need to be referred to, otherwise the linker may exclude them as they are not being referenced. Also, you may need to enforce the order of initialization between different translation units.

When using gcc function can have [constructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2918) attribute. Achieves pretty much the same effect as using C++ constructors.

---

You can force automatic initialization of your library before the first use by using C++ [Nifty Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) idiom. It works for both shared and static libraries.

Here is an example how to do it in plain C:

The header of your library:

```
// lib.h

// These get called by every translation unit including this header file.
extern void lib_ctor();
extern void lib_dtor();

// These are the automatic callers of the above functions.
// Embedded in every translation unit that includes this header.
static void local_lib_ctor() __attribute__((constructor));
static void local_lib_dtor() __attribute__((destructor));
void local_lib_ctor() { lib_ctor(); }
void local_lib_dtor() { lib_dtor(); }

// There rest of lib API.
```

The implementation of the initialization routine:

```
// lib.c

static int ref_counter = 0;

void lib_ctor() {
    if(!ref_counter++) {
        // Do construction here.
    }
}

void lib_dtor() {
    if(!--ref_counter) {
        // Do destruction here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I've been looking at using the constructor attribute already, it's the closest thing I can find, but unfortunately it's still external to the bounds of the linked archive lib. There's an unfortunate reason these initialisers _must_ be called from within the realm of the library code itself, constructor attributed calls are still considered runtime, instead of the needed load-time.

Comment: @mrtimdog Not clear what you call _load-time_. Your executable does not get control until the run-time loader has finished loading the executable and shared libraries. After that the control is passed to `_start` which is normally implemented by libc. This is libc who eventually calls constructor functions and constructors of global objects.

Comment: Sure, I understand that ... to give a little more clarity, this is regarding libcrypto.a from OpenSSL and the FIPS 140-2 implementation. For specific implementation needs see section 9.10, note 3, of [NIST FIPS 140-2](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/fips140-2./FIPS1402IG.pdf). It's basically looking like an unimplementable pain with OpenSSL as is (or likely ever will be, see [here](http://www.opensslfoundation.com/fips/ig95.html)).

Comment: @mrtimdog I see. That NIST paper does recommend using `constructor` function attribute though.